# Finding a missing UIView in xib file

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview

In one of my xib files, I have a UIView as part of a view controller. Only problem is that I can no longer find it on the xib after moving the view to use size classes and applying constraints. The view has an outlet defined, but can't be located in any of the size definitions.

The view exists (it can be seen on the menu if you drill down the into the VC), but can't be selected for editing.

Is there a way to make this view re-appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can find it in the xib/storyboard menu, select it there. Then open the Size Inspector (option-command-5) and change view's x,y location to somewhere you will be able to see it (i.e. 0,0).

Comment: You might also want to reorder the views so it is not hidden behind other views.

Comment: Yep, good point (has happened all too often to me). The xib/storyboard Navigator is a hierarchy, where the files that come first are the ones on top, so all views below it will appear behind that one.

Comment: I've had quite a few things vanish when modifying xib files - they still exist, but (say) resizing a button with the constraints removed causes typical UITextViews to vanish. Such are the pleasures of Xcode I suppose...